# Integrating Devise registration views with backend model:

Tags: model-view-controller, devise

I am using Devise in a project and have followed the steps to get started with Devise being used in my app.

I have also generated Devise views to support registration for my user model. How can I make the backend registration of the user to be integrated with the view?

I read this link 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-Default-Sign_up---Registration-Path-with-Custom-Path

and it suggests devise/sessions#new for both sign in and registration.

Is that an example ? How can I add actions that would enable validation of the fields ? How can I add a successful registration to my database ?

Currently the Signup button redirects and loops me to the same page with login buttons.

What action should I edit in my user controller? Or should I override devise registration controller ?

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to adding a successful user registration to the database devise should be able to do that automatically if you have set it up correctly. Only thing is that you have to try various options in routes file to set up the flow that you want. To add validation to fields you can make  use of the rails helper method 'validates'.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see whats going wrong and help you out.

Comment: sure which code do you want me to share? model, or controller or view?

Comment: you could share your model and controller for now

Comment: actually I haven't done much to be honest. just using devise's logic. I just observed in the logs that my signup page is calling this
/code
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HoSebJcxOSglx62gBW7O6XytnXMo1+tvhmUpicqbn0d8fgaxmrr2qaeIOlcqsbnToQiXn1y8wShMr5dtUFOZrg=="}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (61.6ms)

Any idea how I can generate the controller code automatically?

Comment: Hi! Whatever you have put here wont help me in getting to the root of the problem. Please share some more useful information.